# wanted to sort the wp_query array by two ACF field (Year and month)

Tags: theme-development, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, sort

Want to sort the wp_query by two acf field i have created **month** and **year**, my problem statement is there are multiple post(newsletter) where they have two ACF fields month and year. I able to sort them by single ACF field year in DESC order but now I want to sort them first year then month basis. It means if any year having 4 posts(newsletter) then it sorts by their month name or month value. I have tried for fetching the posts by year when I succeeded but unable to fetch the posts by both ACF field separately.

```
$get_newsletter_query = array(
            'post_type' => 'newsletter', 
            'post_status'=>'publish', 
            'meta_key' => 'newsletter_year',
            'orderby'=>'newsletter_year',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged'=>$paged,
        );
        $newsletter_array = new WP_Query($get_newsletter_query);
```

above code is able to fetch the posts year wise, below code i am trying to fetch the posts by year and month both, but unable to do so.

```
$get_newsletter_query = array(
            'post_type' => 'newsletter', 
            'post_status'=>'publish', 
            'meta_key' => 'newsletter_year',
            'orderby'=>'newsletter_year',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged'=>$paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'newsletter_month'
                )
            )
        );
 $newsletter_array = new WP_Query($get_newsletter_query);
```

please help me in this senario.

Comment: why do you have 2 separate fields rather than a single date field?

Comment: okay fine, i have removed month acf field, but how to sort them on behalf on one acf field contains year and month (2021-02-20) in wp_query

Comment: can you update your question to reflect the new field name and that you now have a single field?